# Destroying values when user exits the application

Tags: android

I am using `SharedPreferences` to know if the user has selected something in the `ViewPager` and passing it onto the relevant fragment.

e.g. if there is a selection then variable `isPassed = 1`

if there is no selection as of yet `isPassed = 0`

**The problem**:

As `SharedPreferences` persists the data and the value `isPassed = 1` is present throughout, which is disturbing my current flow inside the application. So I tried to assign `isPassed=0` in `onDestory` in my `ViewPager` class, but it didn't work.

Could someone suggest any improvements on this ? Or at least suggest me a way to store values until the user is inside the application, and once the user exits the application, all the values are reset. Please do help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then using shared preference make a class and use setter and getter method to set and get the value. Once you exit the application your value also ll be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your information to be persisted outside of the application scope, then `SharedPreferences` is really not the good place.

Why won't you try to store it in the instance of your `Application` class ? This instance will be destroyed rapidly by the system after your user has exited the application.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public static int isPassed=0;
```

It will store value until the user is inside the application, and once the user exits the application, it will reset.

You can use it in another class by `Classname.isPassed=1;`

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a flag you could just create an empty file.
Several ways to create file

```
File myFile =new File(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +  "myFile.txt");
try
  {
   new_file.createNewFile();
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
  }
```

Check if it exists
File myFile = context.getFileStreamPath(FILE_NAME);
if(file.exists())

Delete it
File myFile = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();